# How to use cookies in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I want to use cookies to save some status in angular-dart.
I try it like this:

```
cookies['test']=123;
```

Also init it in constructor and add type(Cookies) in Module, but this can not work.

Comment: If I just use "cookie['test']='test';", it can be work.

Comment: why cookies setter method can not support other type value, such as bool, number?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a bit confusing. Cookies object only supports strings, but silently goes over non-string values. I just opened https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1311 to resolve this into a type-checking error or implicitly call toString().